# Replace non-word characters, unless given sequence matches

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
"Jim-Bob's email @@@hl@@@address@@@endhl@@@ is: jb@example.com"
```

I want to replace all non-word characters (symbols and whitespace), except the `@@@` delimiters.

I'm currently using:

```
str.gsub(/[^\w@]+/, 'X')
```

which yields:

```
"JimXBobXsXemailX@@@hl@@@address@@@endhl@@@XisXjb@exampleXcom"
```

In practice, this is good enough, but it offends me for two reasons:

- The `@` in the email address is not replaced.
- The use of `[^\w]` instead of `\W` feels sloppy.

How do I replace all non-word characters, unless those characters make up the `@@@hl@@@` or `@@@endhl@@@` delimiter strings?

Comment: What would be the desired result for the string `"@@@hl@@@@endhl@@"`?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: what would be the desired result for the string `"@@@hl@@@@endhl@@"`?

Comment: I would consider that bogus data and expect `"XXXhlXXXXendhlXX"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.gsub(/(@@@.*?@@@|\w+)|./) { $1 || "X" }
# => "JimXBobXsXemailX@@@hl@@@address@@@endhl@@@XisXXjbXexampleXcom"
```

This approach uses the fact that alternations work like `case` structure: the first matching one consumes the corresponding string, then no further matching is done on it. Thus, `@@@.*?@@@` will consume a marker (like `@@@hl@@@`; nothing else will be matched inside it. We also match any sequence of word characters. If any of those are captured, we can just return them as-is (`$1`). If not, then we match any other character (i.e. not inside a marker, and not a word character) and replace it with `"X"`.

Comment: Why not post just a simple explanation for future visitors. I like your solution but it's not really an answer unless someone learns something.

Comment: ...I should have posted this question hours ago. I spent much more time puzzling over how to solve it than you did. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second point, I think you are asking too much; there is no simple way to avoid that.

Regarding the first point, a simple way is to temporarily replace `"@@@"` with a character that you will never use (let's say you are using a system without `"\r"`, so that that character is not used; we can use that as a temporal replacement).

```
"Jim-Bob's email @@@hl@@@address@@@endhl@@@ is: jb@example.com"
.gsub("@@@", "\r").gsub(/[^\w\r]/, "X").gsub("\r", "@@@")
# => "JimXBobXsXemailX@@@hl@@@address@@@endhl@@@XisXXjbXexampleXcom"
```

Comment: Inclined to agree on the pedantic nature of my second point, but thought it worth mentioning. I've also definitely considered the two-stage search/replace, but have been trying to avoid too many passes through my string, for readability's sake. Appreciate the solid ideas!